# WPF listview, Load, Save & Add

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a columned listview who's items I would like to store in an XML file.

What's the best way to go about loading, saving and adding items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way is to use MVVM :), that way your View simply represents the data in the UI. Actual DomainModel/BusinessObject resides outside your View.

And then you can use number of persistance methods:

- XML Serialization
- ORM (Object Relation Mapping), which will persist/save the BusinessObject into Database and back

Step by step way:

- Create/Define your BusinessObject(DomainModel, i.e. Person class)
- Use DataTemplate to Bind to Collection from your ListView
- In your ViewModel, you can than say  PersonCollection.Save/Load etc

Comment: Good read here about MVVM, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx